# GKE Autoscaling with a custom metric from deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, autoscaling, stackdriver

I am trying to auto-scale my redis workers based on queue size, I am collecting the metrics using `redis_exporter` and `promethues-to-sd` sidecars in my redis deployment as so:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: master
      image: redis
      env:
        - name: MASTER
          value: "true"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "100m"
        requests:
          cpu: "100m"
    - name: redis-exporter
      image: oliver006/redis_exporter:v0.21.1
      env:
      ports:
        - containerPort: 9121
      args: ["--check-keys=rq*"]
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 100Mi
    - name: prometheus-to-sd
      image: gcr.io/google-containers/prometheus-to-sd:v0.9.2
      command:
        - /monitor
        - --source=:http://localhost:9121
        - --stackdriver-prefix=custom.googleapis.com
        - --pod-id=$(POD_ID)
        - --namespace-id=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
        - --scrape-interval=15s
        - --export-interval=15s
      env:
        - name: POD_ID
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.uid
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 100Mi
```

I can then view the metric (redis_key_size) in Metrics Explorer as:

```
metric.type="custom.googleapis.com/redis_key_size" 
resource.type="gke_container"
```

(I CAN'T view the metric if I change `resource.type=k8_pod`)

However I can't seem to get the HPA to read in these metrics getting a `failed to get metrics error`, and can't seem to figure out the correct `Object` definition.

I've tried both `.object.target.kind=Pod` and `Deployment`, with deployment I get the additional error `"Get namespaced metric by name for resource \"deployments\"" is not implemented`.

I don't know if this issue is related to the `resource.type="gke_container"` and how to change that?

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: {{ template "webapp.backend.fullname" . }}-workers
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ template "webapp.backend.fullname" . }}-workers
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 4
  metrics:
    - type: Object
      object:
        target:
          kind: <not sure>
          name: <not sure>
        metricName: redis_key_size
        targetValue: 4
```

--- Update ---

This works if I use `kind: Pod` and manually set `name` to the pod name created by the deployment, however this is far from perfect.

I also tried this setup using type `Pods`, however the HPA says it can't read the metrics `horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get object metric value: unable to get metric redis_key_size: no metrics returned from custom metrics API`

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: {{ template "webapp.backend.fullname" . }}-workers
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ template "webapp.backend.fullname" . }}-workers
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 4
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: redis_key_size
      targetAverageValue: 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround for deployments it appears that the metrics have to be exported from pods IN the target deployment.

To get this working I had to move the `prometheus-to-sd` container to the deployment I wanted to scale and then scrape the exposed metrics from Redis-Exporter in the Redis deployment via the Redis service, exposing 9121 on the Redis service, and changing the CLA for the the `prometheus-to-sd` container such that:

`- --source=:http://localhost:9121` -> - `--source=:http://my-redis-service:9121`

and then using the HPA

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: {{ template "webapp.backend.fullname" . }}-workers
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ template "webapp.backend.fullname" . }}-workers
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 4
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: redis_key_size
      targetAverageValue: 4
```